# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {z^n}{1+z^n}$ of complex numbers uniformly convergent in $B(0,1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {z^n}{1+z^n}$ of complex numbers uniformly convergent in $B(0,1)$ ? I know it is point-wise convergent in $B(0,1)$ , I also know that it is uniformly convergent in $B[0;r]$ for every $0<r<1$ , but can't figure out about the open domain . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1+z^n}$ for $z=\left(1-\frac1N\right)$.  Does this go to zero as $N\to \infty$?

Comment: It is not uniformly convergent for the set of real numbers $\{z:\,0<z<1\}.$ There is a fairly detailed proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2201677/688046      Idea is let $x\,\uparrow\,1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $E.$ Is that true in this case?