# For what values of $z$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> For what values of $z$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$ convergent?

I tried using the root test, and cannot proceed after obtaining $$\frac{1}{R} = \left|z\right| \text{limsup} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left|1+z^{2n}\right|}}$$

Comment: Compare $f(z)$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$. Anyway, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Can you please link to where the solution is already posted?

Comment: Write the function in the form $(z^n+z^{-n})^{-1}$ and then analyse the case when $|z|>1$ (equivalently when $|z|<1$).

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2201739/44121) deals with a similar series. Notice that your series, as written, is not a power series, so $\frac{1}{R}=|z|\limsup\frac{1}{\sqrt{|1+z^{2n}|}}$ makes no sense.